# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, sbt-idea

i have tried adding sbt plugins on the plugin.sbt of which i added

```
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.2.2")
    resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"
    addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")
```

but when i try the command sbt reload plugin i get this error.
i am not sure of which version is perfec but my scalaversion is 2.12 and my sbtversion is 1.0

```
   [warn]   http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/github/mpeltonen    /sbt-idea_2.12_1.0/1.6.0/sbt-idea-1.6.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/mc-d/.sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt#L12-13)
[warn]        +- org.scala-sbt:global-plugins:0.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:334)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2398)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:263)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:272)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:263)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)    
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException:     unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0:     not     found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

i dont know what to do i have tried changing plugin version but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

According to requirements this plugin is supported for sbt version 0.13 and lower: https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

Comment: thanks i changed to sbt version 0.13 and it works fine